# how to enable opengl es frame capture in xcode 4.3.1

Tags: xcode, opengl-es

Just cannot find UI for enabling the opengl es frame capture.

I know in xcode 4.2 document, the interface is in Edit Scheme as link below. But not found in 4.3 at this place.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/00200-SW1

Comment: Seconded. I attach an iOS 5.1 device (that I was able to capture frames with successfully under Xcode 4.2) but the option documented above is simply missing from the Options panel of the scheme editor for the Run configuration, as is the camera icon when I run the build, and Product.. Debug.. Capture OpenGL ES Frame is greyed out with no explanation or clue. Have tried connecting devices at various points (advice elsewhere suggests connecting before starting Xcode), resetting both device and Mac, twiddling OS deployment version in build settings, all to no avail.

Comment: Update: this appears to be workspace-specific. For some the option is present, for others it is not. It is not obvious what determines it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no longer a check box to enable this.

You need to have the OpenGLES.framework in the Project Navigator for the camera icon to appear. (I have several apps with it included via linker settings, which is not picked up).

If it still fails, try removing it and re-adding it, and also add it to your Build Phases/Link Binary With Libraries. I've found this to be pretty reliable.

Comment: Aha! We're actually using JAM to manage the build process; that build phase was just completely missing from the settings, as JAM invokes the tools directly. Though adding the OpenGLES.framework makes no difference to the binary, it looks like it's needed to make Xcode aware we're using it. Thanks!

Comment: In fact there is a drop-down menu called OpenGL ES Frame Capture which is Automatically Enabled by default. It's in Options tab in Scheme editor for real devices only (it's not shown for simulator)

Answer (score 0):

Capture GPU Frame is greyed out for me when I run a simulator. It seems like it needs a real device.